# How to catch Json request when it's empty and stop it from crashing the Code Excecution in python?

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

```
getsomething = requests.get("https:// url of api")
```

I am trying to get a response from an API using `requests.get("this is a server")`.

The response comes in a JSON format.

However, sometimes the the response can be empty because nothing was found in the API.

Then the code stops execution in Python.

**How can I prevent the empty response from stopping my execution in Python?**

For example, what I want to receive:

```
getsomething.json()['Data']
```

I want to do something like this:

```
if getsomething.json()['Data'] != Empty:
   print(getsomething.json()['Data'])

if getsomething.json()['Data'] == Empty:
   print("Nothing Found In the api Request")
```

How can I do the second `if` in Python?

Comment: What exactly do you want?? Could you provide more code?

Comment: check the question i added some code .

Comment: `if getsomething.json(): ... else: print("nothing was returned")` This is a common FAQ.

Comment: the problem is that the seconds if statement didn't work and the code stop execution, and did not even wait for the if , i want to catch if the response came Empty and print that it's Empty without crashing or Stopping the code Execution .

Comment: guys this is a not a duplicated question . the problem that i am calling a changeable value that keep changing every seconds and the value of  getsomething.json()['Data'] ,  is not a static value it keep changing every second and it's not defined with a stable value .

Comment: i think i figure out a solution for this :

Comment: `if requestfromapi.json()['data']['something'] != KeyError:

   print(requestfromapi.json()['data']['something'])`